# Theorem regarding power series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

The theorem goes : If the series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k(x-x_0)^k$ diverges for $x=x_2$, then the series will diverge for each value of $x$ which satisfies $$\vert x-x_0\vert>\vert x_2-x_0\vert$$

Using the given inequality, and the Cauchy-criterion I can show that $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k(x-x_0)^k$$

does not converge absolutely. This is not useful. Somehow, the proof requires we form a inequality which would lead to the result that $\exists\epsilon>0\forall N_0$, such that $p\geq q \geq N_0$ implies $$\bigg\vert \sum_{k=q}
^{p}a_k(x-x_0)^k\bigg\vert\geq\epsilon$$

I can't think of any other way to show divergence. I'm doing this proof without invoking the concept of radius of convergence.

Comment: Can you show it the other way around? If the series converges for some $x$ then it converges (absolute) for all other $x$ which are closer to the center $x_0$. That should be covered in every book or course on power series.

Comment: Yeah I can do it

Comment: Are you saying that the proof of that theorem implies something about this one?

Comment: Have you ever encountered the law of the contrapositive? Proof by contradiction? Yes, Martin R is hinting that the other result is very useful for proving this one.

Comment: try looking at the supremum of the set $\{ r : \{a_nr^n\}_n is bounded \}$ and choose $r$ appropriately.